# Firefox SDK block content-type

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an add-on for Firefox and i want to block a special kind of requests in content-type.

For example i want to block the `application/x-rar` content-types and show a message in console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to intercept the requests by observing the [http-on-examine-response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications#HTTP_requests) notification event and check [`getResponseHeader('Content-Type')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel#getResponseHeader()) for `application/x-rar`.

```
'use strict';
const {
  Ci, Cr
} = require('chrome');
const events = require('sdk/system/events');

events.on('http-on-examine-response', function(event) {
  let channel = event.subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
  let contentType = channel.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
  if(contentType === 'applicaiton/x-rar'){
    event.subject.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
    console.log('Aborted Request', channel.name);
  }
});
```

Best of luck with developing your add-on.